# Why am I having to pay again to listen to songs I already paid for at the ITunes store?

Tags: itunes-store

Why am I having to pay again to listen to songs I already paid for at the ITunes store?
I'm getting a msg saying something about paying again to download over cellular.

Comment: Are you sure the message is not warning you that downloading over cellular may incur charges by your carrier?  That is not a iTunes (Apple) charge, it is a warning in case your carrier (data provider) charges you for exceeding your data limit.  Please add more details to your question (device you are using, iPhone or iPad? Exact message text, etc.) and welcome to Ask Different.

Answer (score 1):

Do redownload past purchase for free you have to follow this :  https://support.apple.com/en-ie/HT201272 other option would probably charge you for multiple reasons